# Pop up window opens when user presses the back button in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, popup, back-button

I am using asp.net and C# to build win form application. I have used following code to open a popup window.

```
string url = "../approvalScreen.aspx";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=650,height=300,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

The problem is when I open and close the pop up and then presses the browser back button (After closing the pop up), pop up opens again. Pop up opens on the back button same no. of times that the user open it through user click. If the user hasn't open and close the pop up, then it wont open on back button as well.